# How to get globalization for jquery validation in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget-package, jquery-globalize, cldr

I use VS 2017 and I have an MVC 5 project.
I used NuGet to install `jQuery.Validation.Globalize`. Which also installed as dependencies:

- `jquery-globalize (>= 1.0.0)`
- `cldrjs`

I included the following javascript files:

> "~/Scripts/cldr.js",
>   "~/Scripts/cldr/*.js",
>
>   "~/Scripts/globalize.js",
>
>   "~/Scripts/globalize/*.js",
>   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"

But it misses the `cldr-data`: the JSON files which contain the localized data.
How to get it with NuGet or with Visual Studio in a MVC 5 project?

Answer (score 1):

For .NET MVC, you have to get the cldr-data json files manually from the unicode-cldr repository:

See https://github.com/unicode-cldr/ for full list